# How to display Emgu.CV.Mat in the console?

Tags: c#, printing, emgucv

After some research without finding a solution, I would like to know if there was a (**fairly simple**) way to display a variable of type **Emgu.CV.Mat** in the form of a list **without** going through a conversion of **Emgu.CV.Mat to Emgu.CV.Image <Gray, byte>** by looping on each pixel.

Thank you.

Comment: What format do you mean to display?  Comma separated pixel values?  As RGB triplets?  With alpha? Zeroes and Ones? Something else? What bit depth of pixels?

Comment: for the moment i just have Mat in Gray format, but maybe will need RGB format after

Comment: As far as I know, this is not possible in any simple way, since values are not directly accessible in `Mat`.  So you would either need to convert it to an image, or use unsafe code to access Values. Or use the `Matrix<T>` class.

Comment: I just tried using Matrix as well, however there isn't a straightforward way: / always loop over pixels. thanks anyway

Comment: Yea, as far as I know, you will always need to loop over the pixels. But with `Image/Matrix<T>` you can at least access the values. And it should be easy enough to write a simple extension method to do this.

Comment: Yes, i thank u :)